# questions regarding multi threading

Tags: java, multithreading

1. Thread class is said to have a "IS-a" relation as well as "Has-a" relation with the runnable interface. What is the benefit of having both of these?
2. Why do we give priority to "Has-a" relation?

Comment: Where did you hear this?

Comment: the thread class implements runnable,therefore it has is-a relation,and in its constructors,there is a reference of the interface therefore has-a relation.

Comment: @LutzHorn - assignment question, surely.

Answer (score 5):

> What is the benefit of having both of these?

It was a poor design choice, IMO. It would have been cleaner to avoid `Thread` implementing `Runnable` in the first place. This has led to various bugs (as witnessed by questions on Stack Overflow) where people have called `run` on a `Thread` instead of `start`.

> Why do we give priority to "Has-a" relation?

Composition is generally more flexible than inheritance. If you create a `Runnable` implementation you can pass that to an `ExecutorService` instead of a `Thread`, for example. You aren't tying yourself to one particular way of executing the action - you're just saying "this is the code I want to run."

Comment: Regarding calling people using run() in stead of start() a design mistake: okay it is a design mistake, but that is not the reason; the only real problem is that people refuse to read the documentation.

Comment: @Gimby: I disagree. Yes, the bug is clearly on the part of the person who didn't read the documentation - but a well-designed API is easy to use well and hard to use badly. That's just not the case here. Just because the documentation says what's going to happen doesn't mean it's a clean API. Take `java.util.Calendar` for example: it's documented in all its hideousness, but Joda Time is still a much better API in general, even though that's *not* as thoroughly documented.